# plot vertical color line in R

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot multiple color vertical line for a time series as below,

```
    [1,] 4.698478   0
    [2,] 4.698205   1
    [3,] 4.698569   0
    [4,] 4.697385   -1
    ...
```

to plot a blue color vertical line when [,2] is 1, and a red line when [,2] is -1, wonder if someone can help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following, assuming `data[, 1]` is the x-value for the vertical line:

```
abline(v = data[data[, 2] == 1, 1], col = 'blue')
abline(v = data[data[, 2] == -1, 1], col = 'red')
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with @ChristopherLouden's answer, but this would be a way to do it in a single call to `abline`:

```
abline(v=m[,1], col=c('red', NA, 'blue')[as.numeric(as.factor(m[,2]))])
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using quantmod's charting function, pretty good results.

```
chartSeries(price[,1])
addTA(price[,2]==1,pch=1, on=1,col="blue")
addTA(price[,2]==-1,pch=1, on=1,col="red")
```